# Difficult Laplace Transform Type of Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, integral-transforms

Good afternoon.  I have the following integral that I need help integrating;

$$
\mathrm{F}\left(x\right) =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{s\left(j - 1/x\right)}\,
\left[\mathrm{T}_{N}\left(s\right)\right]^{k - j}\,\mathrm{d}s
$$

where $\mathrm{T}_{N}\left(s\right)$ is the truncated exponential function
$$
\mathrm{T}_{N}\left(s\right) = \sum_{n = 0}^{N}\frac{s^{n}}{n!}
$$

and $j,k$ are whole numbers.

I figured that tackling this using integration by parts is the best choice, but naturally this could take a while given that my choice of $u_{1}=\mathrm{T}_{N}^{k - j}\left(s\right)$ yields a $\mathrm{d}u_{1}$ of
$$
\mathrm{d}u_{1} =
\left(k - j\right)\mathrm{T}_{N}^{k-j-1}\left(s\right)
\mathrm{T}_{N - 1}\left(s\right)\,\mathrm{d}s
$$
since $\mathrm{d}\mathrm{T}_{N}\left(s\right)/\mathrm{d}s = \mathrm{T}_{N - 1}\left(s\right)$.  This does not seem to be simplifying the problem though as the next iteration would require me to then choose my $u_{2}$ to be
$$
u_{2} =
\frac{1}{k - j}\,\frac{\mathrm{d}u_{1}}{\mathrm{d}s} =
\mathrm{T}_{N}^{k - j - 1}\left(s\right)
\mathrm{T}_{N - 1}\left(s\right)
$$

Are there any other approaches to this without this drawn out *IBP* method or without considering expanding the truncated exponential ?.

Comment: There was an answer here but it was deleted due to an objection I had... but I had an idea and if that person could put it back or "undelete it" it would help... I think I know how to resolve it...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126348/are-my-deleted-answers-visible-to-others

Comment: here it says that a moderator or 10k+ reputation account can view deleted answers. Maybe you can get one of them to help you put it up again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as $j < 1/x$ it is possible to write the function as a finite sum of terms (i.e., in closed form) by writing the power of the truncated exponential as a polynomial, and then turning the integral into a polynomial sum of gamma functions.  If we apply the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) we can write the power of the truncated exponential as a polynomial of degree $N(k-j)$ as follow:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\left[ \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{s^n}{n!} \right]^{k-j}
&= \sum_{r_0 + \cdots + r_N = k-j} {k-j \choose \mathbf{r}} \prod_{n=0}^N \Big( \frac{s^n}{n!} \Big)^{r_n} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{r_0 + \cdots + r_N = k-j} \frac{(k-j)!}{\prod_{n=0}^N (r_n!) (n!)^{r_n}} \prod_{n=0}^N s^{n \cdot r_n} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{r_0 + \cdots + r_N = k-j} \frac{(k-j)!}{\prod_{n=0}^N (r_n!) (n!)^{r_n}} s^{\sum_{n=0}^N  n \cdot r_n} \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N(k-j)} a_i s^i, \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

where the coefficients $a_0,a_1,...,a_{N(k-j)}$ depend on $N$ and $k-j$, and are obtained from this multinomial summation.  We then have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
F(x) 
&= \int \limits_0^\infty e^{s (j-\frac{1}{x})} \left[ \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{s^n}{n!} \right]^{k-j} ds \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^\infty e^{s (j-\frac{1}{x})} \sum_{i=0}^{N(k-j)} a_i s^i \ ds \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N(k-j)} a_i \int \limits_0^\infty e^{s (j-\frac{1}{x})} s^i \ ds \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Now, assume that $j < 1/x$ so that $(j-\tfrac{1}{x}) <0$.  In this case we can use the change-of-variable $m = s |j-\frac{1}{x}|$ to get $dm = -j ds$ and we have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
F(x) 
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N(k-j)} a_i \int \limits_0^\infty e^{-s |j-\frac{1}{x}|} s^i \ ds \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N(k-j)} a_i \cdot \frac{1}{(-j) |j - \frac{1}{x}|^i} \int \limits_0^\infty e^{-s |j-\frac{1}{x}|} (s |j-\tfrac{1}{x}|)^i \ (-j) \ ds \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N(k-j)} a_i \cdot \frac{1}{(-j) |j - \frac{1}{x}|^i} \int \limits_0^\infty e^{-m} m^i \ dm \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=0}^{N(k-j)} a_i \cdot \frac{i!}{(-j) |j - \frac{1}{x}|^i}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This form of the function is a finite sum, where the only serious difficulty (for large $N$ or $k-j$) is to calculate the polynomial coefficients $a_0,a_1,...,a_{N(k-j)}$.  Calculation of these coefficients may be cumbersome for large degree, but once they are calculated the function is then amenable to calculation.

Comment: The answer I mentioned that was deleted had a similar expansion for the powered truncated exponential... I felt that it could be written as a sum of powers of $s$ better than that answerer did...I like where this is going... I suppose on first glance, those polynomial coefficients are hard to find a nice form for...  Perhaps looking at small values of $N$ first and looking for pattern using computational methods could help here?

Comment: Yes; I'm not sure of any simple recursion for the coefficients, but maybe some pattern could be found to assist this.

Answer (score 4):

I have only a partial answer: it pretty much just consists of repeated integration by parts, so maybe this isn't what you're looking for.

Write $A(n_1, \dots, n_r) = \int_0^\infty e^{-as} \prod_i T_{n_i}(s) \,ds$. Then integration by parts gives 
\begin{align*}
A(n_1, \dots, n_r) 
&= -\frac{1}{a}\bigg[e^{-as}\prod_i T_{n_i}(s)\bigg]\bigg|_0^\infty + \frac{1}{a}\sum_{j : n_j > 0} \int_0^\infty e^{-as} T_{n_j - 1}(s)\prod_{i \neq j} T_{n_i}(s) \,ds \\
&= \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a} \sum_{j : n_j > 0} A(n_1, \dots, n_j - 1, \dots, n_r)
\end{align*}
when all $n_i \geq 0$.

To make things a little easier, let's take $T_n(s) = 0$ when $n < 0$ (this is consistent with the identity $T_n'(s) = T_{n-1}(s)$), so we'll have $A(n_1, \dots, n_r) = 0$ when some $n_i < 0$, and so we can write
$$A(n_1, \dots, n_r) = \frac{1}{a}\bigg(\mathbb{1}_{(n_i)} + \sum_i A(n_1, \dots, n_i - 1, \dots, n_r)\bigg)$$
for any integers $n_1, \dots, n_r$, where $\mathbb{1}_{(n_i)} = 1$ if all $n_i \geq 0$ and is $0$ otherwise.

Letting $f(x_1, \dots, x_r) = \sum A(n_1, \dots, n_r) x_1^{n_1} \cdots x_r^{n_r}$ be the generating function of $A$, this identity gives
$$af = \frac{1}{(1-x_1) \cdots (1-x_r)} + (x_1 + \cdots + x_r)f$$
hence
\begin{align*}
f 
&= \frac{1}{(1 - x_1) \cdots (1 - x_r)(a - x_1 - \cdots - x_r)} \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \sum_{l_1, \dots, l_r, m_1, \dots, m_r} a^{-m_1 - \cdots - m_r}\binom{m_1 + \cdots + m_r}{m_1, \dots, m_r} x_1^{l_1 + m_1} \cdots x_r^{l_r + m_r} \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \sum_{n_1, \dots, n_r} \sum_{0 \leq m_i \leq n_i} a^{-m_1 - \cdots - m_r}\binom{m_1 + \cdots + m_r}{m_1, \dots, m_r} x_1^{n_1} \cdots x_r^{n_r} \\
\end{align*}
and finally,
$$A(n_1, \dots, n_r) = \frac{1}{a} \sum_{0 \leq m_i \leq n_i} a^{-m_1 - \cdots - m_r}\binom{m_1 + \cdots + m_r}{m_1, \dots, m_r} $$
(this could alternatively be found by repeatedly expanding the recurrence).

The case relevant to the question is the one where $n_1 = \cdots = n_r = N$, $r = k-j$, $a = 1/x - j$, but I'm not sure how to simplify this sum. I've been thinking about it in terms of lattice paths in $r$ dimensions: in particular the coefficient of $a^{-t}$ is the number of lattice paths of length $t$ where we have at most $n_i$ steps in the $i$-th direction for each $i$, but that doesn't seem to help simplify any further.

As noted by DinosaurEgg, we're only interested in 
$$A(N, \dots, N) = \frac{1}{a} \sum_{0 \leq m_i \leq N} a^{-m_1 - \cdots - m_r}\binom{m_1 + \cdots + m_r}{m_1, \dots, m_r}$$
but this sum still seems difficult to simplify to me, because of the $m_i \leq N$ constraints.

Comment: I love what you did here, but I am giving the bounty to @ben, only because his work is closer to all that I have done with my calculations over the last couple of weeks.  I definitely liked your approach though and will be referring to it as I continue.  Thank you for your effort.